# Does there exist any continuous injection map from $f : [a,b] \to (a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Does there exist any continuous map  $f : [a,b] \to (a,b)$ such that $f$ is one-one.?

I am unable to find a counter example.

Give me some hint.

Comment: Of course: consider $[a+\varepsilon, \, b-\varepsilon] $ for small enough $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ such that $[a + \epsilon, b - \epsilon] \subset (a, b).$ Then you can easily construct a bijective continous map $f: [a, b] \to [a + \epsilon, b - \epsilon]$.

Note that the map can't bijectively map to $(a, b)$ since it is not compact.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a continuous, injective map *onto* $(a,b)$, consider a compactness argument